# Could not find a declaration file for module 'vuelidate'

Tags: typescript, vue.js, visual-studio-code

In Vuejs, while following the Vuelidate installation instructions (https://vuelidate.js.org/#getting-started), I get a warning at:

`import Vuelidate from 'vuelidate'`

The warning says:

> Could not find a declaration file for module 'vuelidate'. 'c:/Users/[myUser]/../../index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
> Try `npm install @types/vuelidate` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'vuelidate';`ts(7016)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it appears you are using typescript, and thus Vue requires a [type declaration file](https://www.geekabyte.io/2017/10/understanding-declaration-files-in.html) for all Vuelidate methods and properties. If you run `npm install @types/vuelidate` as suggested, the error should go away.

In the future, if you are working with an npm module that has not published types through npm, you will have to [write the declaration file yourself](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html), but don't worry about it for now.

Comment: Thank you! I came back to publish the answer since, as you are saying, running the suggested command: `npm install @types/vuelidate` fixed my issue! Thanks again!

Comment: True enough but that guide is several years old and suggests some outdated practices