# vuelidate module not found

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, vuelidate

Trying to use the https://vuelidate-next.netlify.app/ module for validation. Using VueJs2 Have the below code in app.js.  when I do npm run watch am getting the below error
"ERROR in ./modules/sell/Resources/js/app.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'vuelidate' "

Tried installing the npm install @types/vuelidate found in [Could not find a declaration file for module 'vuelidate'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63908945/could-not-find-a-declaration-file-for-module-vuelidate) but it doesn't seem to work.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuelidate from 'vuelidate'
import router from './router/index.js'
import store from './store'
require('./utils/fontAwesomeIcons')

import ResellerApp from "./App.vue"
Vue.use(Vuelidate);
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    store,
    router,
    components: {
        ResellerApp,
    },
});
```

Comment: Are you seeing vuelidate in your node modules?

Comment: Which version did you installed?

Comment: can see the @vuelidate directory under node_modules   in package-lock.json
 "@vuelidate/core": {
            "version": "2.0.0-alpha.40",
      
        },
        "@vuelidate/validators": {
            "version": "2.0.0-alpha.28",
        },

Comment: Check it in the `package.json` rather.

Comment: package.json
        "@vue/composition-api": "^1.4.9",
        "@vuelidate/core": "^2.0.0-alpha.40",
        "@vuelidate/validators": "^2.0.0-alpha.28",

Answer (score 1):

The new Vuelidate version states that you need to import the library using the following command:
`import { useVuelidate } from '@vuelidate/core'`

Here's the link about the migration to the newer version:
https://vuelidate-next.netlify.app/migration_guide.html#package-name-and-imports